# Attach image to ACTION_SEND then delete after

Tags: android, image, email, attachment, delete-file

I'm creating an ACTION_SEND intent in android and attaching an image file with the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/html");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Receipt From: XXX");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

byte[] b = Base64.decode(signature, Base64.DEFAULT); //Where signature is a base64 encoded string
final Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);

String path = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), mBitmap, "signature", null);
Uri sigURI = Uri.parse(path);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, sigURI);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"));
```

This works, the image is attached to the email. However I'm having trouble deleting the image afterwords.  The images are getting stored in the DCIM\Camera folder with a large number as the file name.

I've tried

```
File tempFile = File(getRealPathFromURI(sigURI)); //a subroutine which gives me the full path
tempFile.delete();
```

tempFile.delete returns true, however the file is still there.
One odd thing I noticed is that the image saved is of file size 0 and appears empty both before and after I try to delete.

How do I properly delete this image after sending it with the email? Or is there an alternative way of attaching the image without saving it?

Also, not the main question here but if you could include how to change the name of the image/attachment from 1375729812685.jpg (or what ever the number may be) to something else, I'de appreciate it.

As a last note, I've been testing on an HTC Evo if it makes any difference.

Comment: It will not work because users may not choose gmail, but they would choose some other application like dropbox or picasa, or any application that supports `ACTION_SEND`

Comment: @vorrtex Yes, I'm aware that ACTION_SEND provides more than just Gmail and Email. This currently isn't my concern. I'm more concerned about the image being saved on the device. I'de prefer it not be saved at all but from what I read, that doesn't appear to be possible. So I'm looking for a way of deleting the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution for anyone who is interested.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{});
intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_CC, new String[ {"test@test.net"});
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Receipt From: " + receipt[1]);


String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US).format(new Date());
String imageFileName = "IMG_" + timeStamp + "_";
File albumF = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "Receipt");

if (albumF != null) {
    if (! albumF.mkdirs()) {
        if (! albumF.exists()){
            Log.d("CameraSample", "failed to create directory");
            return;
         }
    }
}

File imageF = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", albumF);
byte[] b = Base64.decode(sig, Base64.DEFAULT);
if (b.length > 0) {
    Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
    FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(imageF);
    mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, ostream);
    ostream.flush();
    ostream.close();

    Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(imageF);

    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri);
}


intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
intent.setType("message/rfc822");

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email Using"));
```

Comment: where/why does the delete happen?